# Is it bad design to create a database where rows reference each other?

Tags: database-design

Assume I have a database where each row corresponds to a task that I have to do. Is it bad design if one column is "tasks that have to be finished before this task can be started"? That is, is it ok for each row to have a list of indices of other rows? If this is bad design, how would one solve such situations?

Comment: Self-referencing is not exotic.

Comment: However, "each row to have a list of indices of other rows" is a Bad Idea™, because it violates 1NF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to have a column of tasks:

```
Task  | ParentTasks
A     | B, D, E
```

Yes, that is bad design.  It breaks 1st normal form (atomicity) which was put in place for a good reason.

Instead you should create an associative table to reference the dependencies:

```
Task | ParentTask
A    | B
A    | D
A    | E
```

In this case the primary key is `(Task,ParentTask)` although it makes sense for query optimization to have an alternate key `(ParentTask,Task)` so you can find all of the dependencies for a given `Task` without scanning the whole table.

You will need to put some functionality in place to ensure you don't create a circular reference such as:

```
Task | ParentTask
A    | B
B    | C
C    | A
```

Now one could ask: why is it bad to violate 1st normal form, and the answer is:

1. You cannot guarantee referential integrity through a foreign key
2. You cannot use a declarative language such as SQL to join to each parent `Task` or find all dependent `Tasks`
3. The most efficient indexing method that will allow you to find all dependencies for a given `Task` looks exactly like the associative table above and storing that information any other way provides no benefit